# Assignment operator and deep copy

Tags: c++

I'm learning C++ and there is something I don't get about assignment operators. As far as I understand, they are supposed to provide deep copies of object. Here is an example

```
Test::Test(int i){
    value = i;
}

Test& Test::operator=(const Test& rhs){
    value = rhs.value;
    return *this;
}
```

Now:

```
Test* t1 = new Test(1);
Test* t2 = t1;  //t2 should be now a deep copy of t1
t1->value = 2;
cout << t1->value;
cout << t2->value;
```

Output is `22` but I expected '21'. What is the obvious thing I am missing here?

Comment: There's no assignment going on, and you shouldn't need any pointers like that to create objects. Your assignment operator basically does what the default one does, and your constructor would be better off with a constructor initialization list.

Comment: A copy assignment can do either a deep copy _or_ a shallow copy. It all depends on the requirements of the class and you shouldn't assume one or the other is always supposed to happen.

Comment: A copy always copies the _value_  of an object.  So the question is, what is the _value_ of the object?  For a string, or a vector, that is it's contents, thus it acts like a deep copy.  A pointer however, the value is the address of the pointee, so that act like a shallow copy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Short answer

As Captain Obvlious suggests, call your assignment operator with

```
Test t2 = *t1
```

### "Longer" answer

With this line

```
Test* t2 = t1
```

You are just making an assignment between pointers, so you are declaring a pointer to `Test` called `t2` which will hold the same address held by the pointer `t1`.

When you modify the object using `t1`, you are actually changing the same object that also `t2` is pointing to (this explains the output).

If you want to copy `t1`, you should use one of the following two ways:

**Create a new `Test` object and copy construct it with `t1`:**

```
Test t1;
Test t2(t1)
```

This code will call the copy constructor of the class `Test`:

```
Test::Test(const Test& t);
```

**Use the assignment operator on an existing `Test` object:**

```
Test t2;
t2 = t1;
```

As a general rule of thumb, when you need to define an `operator=`, then you probably need to define also a `copy constructor` and a `destructor`.

See the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) for more details.

Comment: This.  No copying of any kind is taking place, the assignment operator isn't getting called, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: How about `Test t2 = *t1` as a solution for the OP ;)

Comment: @CaptainObvlious will add that as a short answer :)